# embedding script in an html element

Tags: javascript, html

How to embedded a small piece of code into an HTML element (such as height= align= width= or role=) (not html tags)?
This is for doing something very simple like the multiplication of a dom element by a fixed number.
I've seen `href="javascript:script_code"` but this seems to be valid only for `href`, since it don't work with other elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can't (not even for `href` attributes: `javascript:foo()` returns the document to be rendered not the URL to fetch that document from).

Either generate the entire element from JavaScript, or modify it through the DOM afterwards.

Comment: The problem for me is that I'm in a special situation were a script tag is likely to filtered by the parser however, code inside an html element wouldn't be filtered.

Comment: If there was a way to embed JavaScript in that fashion then any XSS filter worth its salt would filter that out too.

Comment: It's off-topic, but does `foo()` in `javascript:foo()` need to return a String?